# How to perform mixed logit model with heterogeneity in mean and variance in software?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, stata

Currently I am learning this model with some papers published in journals, then not in detail. It is named as random parameter logit model with heterogeneity in mean and variance (maybe another name in other majors). Roughly description, random parameter allow the estimation vary from individual to another with an assumed distribution, with heterogeneity in mean and variance method made a change a little bit, add attributes capture the mean and variance in the equation. See formulas below. Now I just wonder which software or package can perform it? Reference: Unobserved Heterogeneity and the Statistical Analysis of Highway Accident Data
[image]

Comment: Please don't embed a picture from a paper in your question. Please write the variables, the model, it's assumptions, any anything else needed for us to understand what you are asking, into the question itself. The site supports excellent $\LaTeX$-style formatting (actually MathJax)

Comment: This is based on a growth curve (longitudinal model), but the idea hold whether you have longitudinal or cross-sectional data: https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/sites/qdev/files/ILD_Ch06_2017_MLMwithHeterogeneousVariance.html